# Join 2 tables in mysql by removing duplicate columns to create a new table

Tags: mysql, join, union, create-table, union-all

**Available Data**

Name of Table1 : 'table1'

Join Column of Table1 : 'column1'

Other columns of Table1: Unknown

Name of Table2 : 'table2'

Join Column of Table2 : 'column2'

Other columns of Table2 : Unknown

**Task** : Create a new Table by joining two tables table1 and table2 based on table1.column1 = table2.column2. New table should have all the columns of table1 and table2 without duplicate columns(The schema of new table should be similar to schema of table1 and table2 combined). And also it should have only those rows that satisfy the condition given above .

**What I tried** :

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS ( 
    SELECT * FROM table1, table2 
    WHERE table1.column1=table2.column2
)
```

**Result I got** : I am getting proper results for the above query if all the columns are unique. But if there are columns with same names, i'm getting an **error: column 'column3' specified more than once** because column3 is common in both the tables. The main problem is i will not be given the schema of either table1 or table2.

Please provide me a query to remove the duplicate column ( like 'column3' mentioned above ) while creating new table. A complete new query is also accepted

I tried UNION ALL but it's not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write dynamic SQL that gets all the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and removes the duplicates.

Comment: You can't do it with an ordinary query.